# Static Variables in Python C API

Tags: python, python-c-api

How would one expose "static" variables like this

```
class MyClass:
    X = 1
    Y = 2
```

via the C API? The only variable on the PyTypeObject that looks like it would work is tp_members, but I see no flag in the PyMemberDef to indicate that the member should be per-class, not per-instance.

For a bit more clarification, since it may change the answer, I'm trying to expose a C enum to Python such that the enumeration

```
enum MyFlags {
    Alpha = 0,
    Beta = 1
};
```

Can be accessed in Python as:

```
module.MyFlags.Alpha
module.MyFlags.Beta
```

Comment: I only found this SO question after I had figured out the answer myself. Prior to that I searched for things like "cpython class constants". I wonder if we could add more words to this question that could help other people find this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just put them in the type's [tp_dict](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_dict) e.g. with [PyDict_SetItemString](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/dict.html#c.PyDict_SetItemString).

Comment: Excellent! That's what I was looking for. (You'll excuse me if I take a moment to test it out before marking this as answered.)

Comment: Works as advertised. :) Thanks again.

Comment: Since the time this answer was originally posted, the following warning has been added to the docs: "**Warning:** It is not safe to use PyDict_SetItem() on or otherwise modify tp_dict with the dictionary C-API."

Comment: I *think* that warning is a bit broader than it should be - it should be okay to set entries in `tp_dict` as long as the names don't have any corresponding slots (so no setting `__add__` or `__new__` or stuff like that) and you call `PyType_Modified` on the type afterward.