# How do I set a static class variable in C for Python?

Tags: python, c, cpython

According to Python documentation, implementing a class in C for Python can be roughly divided into three steps:

1. defining the Object (the data impl)
2. defining the Type (the behavior wrapper)
3. defining concrete behaviors, and set them into corresponding `tp_xx` slots

For `new` function, `init` function, instance members, attributes, and even `dealloc`, all of them can be found a **slot** in `PyTypeObject` declaration, like `tp_new`, `tp_init`, `tp_members`, `tp_methods` and `tp_dealloc`. But there is not a slot like `tp_statics`.

Where should I declare the static variables and where should I set them up? I searched for the internet but got nothing. Could anyone give me a clue about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374334/static-variables-in-python-c-api).

There is no `static` keyword in Python, class attributes are stored in `class.__dict__`.

Answer (score 0):

@avram has mentioned an answer which solved my problem.
But for anyone who found that your static attributes does not get updated after modification, you may check [PyType_Modified](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/type.html#c.PyType_Modified) function.