# How to set __file__ and __module__ for object types implemented in C?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a few custom types defined in C code.

When developing Python code based on these, I sometimes encounter an error, which is compounded when Python's own `getfile()` function (inside `inspect.py`) raises its own exception:

`TypeError('{!r} is a built-in class'.format(object))`

Because I'd like to see the underlying original error instead of the above, I'm wondering, if I can add the `__module__` and the `__file__` attributes to my own types. How would one do that?

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/newtypes.html#attribute-management) seems to imply, attributes must be part of the object -- an obvious waste in the case like mine, when the values are exactly the same for all instances of the class -- how can I make them *static*?

If I try to implement [type-specific attribute management](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/newtypes.html#type-specific-attribute-management), I suddenly lose access to the type's *methods* (because now they are treated as attributes).

Is it possible for such attributes to coexist with methods? How would I do that? My main target is Python-3.x...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `tp_name` slot of your C-level type definition, write the fully-qualified name:

```
"your_module.YourClass"
```

The `__module__` of the type object will be set based on `tp_name`. The `__file__` attribute of the module should already be handled automatically.

Comment: Thanks! This solves my particular problem. Still, I wonder, how would one have custom _static_ attributes without losing access to methods...

Comment: @MikhailT.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374334/static-variables-in-python-c-api, but it's the wrong thing to do for `__module__`.